# Split large line in to smaller lines and insert special character at the beginning of newline

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing large lines. The lines should be divided into separate lines after two characters, and the new line should have // appended at the beginning.

What I have :

```
MEANDER_XY
MEANDER_WS
```

What is required :

```
ME
//AN
//DE
//R_X
//Y
ME
//AN
//DE
//R_W
//S
```

I have used `sed -e 's/.\{2\}/&\n/g'`. The line is getting divided but I also need `//` to be appended as shown.

Comment: wrt `after two characters` - You have a 3-char substring in your output, `R_W` so please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements or fix your example.

Comment: Do you need to use `sed`? What's about `awk`?

Comment: What do you want the output to be of "MEANDERS_XY"?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[A-Z]_\?[A-Z]/&\n\/\//g' file
```

Match an uppercase A thru Z, followed by an optional underscore, followed by another uppercase A thru Z and replace it by itself, followed by a newline, followed by  two back slashes, globally.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, tested with your given examples.

```
awk '
{
  count=""
  while($0){
    if(match($0,/[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]/)){
       value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
       if(++count>1){
          print "//"value
       }
       else{
          print value
       }
       $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    else{
       if(length($0)){
          print "//" $0
          next
       }
    }
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. I can get the expected result using the provided script. Could you please let me know the changes if I have a very large line and If I have to break the line after 500 characters instead of 2 characters ? Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your update Ravinder. Unfortunately it did not work. Meanwhile I have tried some thing in sed --> sed -e 's/.\{500\}/&\n\/i/g' file, but could not print "//" instead I can print only "/" all the times :)

Comment: This worked -> sed -e 's/.\{500\}/&\n\/\/i/g' file :)

Comment: @BharathAbhishek, we could do so, but in your shown samples in between non-alpha characters are there too, so I went for this approach; I would suggest you to edit my answer(add yours too in it) and you could then select this answer as an correct one too, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk, you can define fields by their pattern using `FPAT` (See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content)). You state:

> The lines should be divided into separate lines after **two characters**, and the new line should have // appended at the beginning.

Your output however assumes **two alphabetic characters**. The pattern you are after is:

```
FPAT=""[^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]]?"
```

It searches for one or two alphabetic characters at most which can be preceaded or interleaved with non-alphabetic characters. (not ended):

```
 MEANDER_XY -> ME\n//AN\n//DE\n//R_X\n//Y
 MEANDERS_XY -> ME\n//AN\n//DE\n//RS\n//_XY
```

So, the following awk will do the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=""[^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]]?"; OFS="\n//"}{$1=$1}1'
```

Using POSIX awk, you can do the more extended version that will always work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{regex=""[^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*[[:alpha:]]"; OFS="\n//"}
     { s=$0
       while(match(s,regex)) {
          printf substr(s,RSTART,RLENGTH) (length(s)==RLENGTH ? "": OFS)
          s=substr(s,RLENGTH+1)
       }
       print s
     }'
```